# Views not updated from callback of asynctask after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-asynctask

I have an activity with a fragment with retainedInstance = true, defined on its onCreate() method, the fragment will do some networking and then it sends the data back to the activity.

This is my callback function

```
override fun updateUi(result: ArrayList<Person>?) {
    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    if (result != null) {
        setAdapter(result)
    }
    else {
        finishNetworking()
        val snackBar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.root_layout),
            "Network failure", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        snackBar.setAction("Try again") {
            startDownload()
        }
        snackBar.show()
    }
}
```

and this is my activity onCreate()

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)
    recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view).apply {
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        layoutManager = viewManager
    }

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        hasArgs = false
        networkFragment = NetworkFragment.getInstance(supportFragmentManager, SWAPI_URL_PEOPLE, null)
    }
    else {
        hasArgs = true
        networking = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("networking", false)
        if (networking) {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        }
        if (savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList<Person>("persons") != null) {
            setAdapter(savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList<Person>("persons") as ArrayList<Person>)
        }
    }

}
```

Heres is my AsyncTask

```
private class NetworkTask(
    callback: NetworkCallback<ArrayList<Person>>,
    person: Person?
)
    : AsyncTask<String, Int, NetworkTask.Result>() {

    private val mCallback: NetworkCallback<ArrayList<Person>>? = callback
    private val mPerson: Person? = person

    internal class Result {
        var mResultValue: ArrayList<Person>? = null
        var mException: Exception? = null

        constructor(resultValue: ArrayList<Person>?) {
            mResultValue = resultValue
        }

        constructor(exception: Exception) {
            mException = exception
        }
    }

    override fun onPreExecute() {

        if (mCallback != null) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
                val networkInfo = mCallback.getConnectivityManager().activeNetworkInfo
                if (networkInfo?.isConnected == false
                    || networkInfo?.type != ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI
                    && networkInfo?.type != ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    mCallback.updateUi(null)
                    cancel(true)
                }
            }
            else {
                val network = mCallback.getConnectivityManager().activeNetwork
                val networkCapabilities = mCallback.getConnectivityManager().getNetworkCapabilities(network)
                if (networkCapabilities?.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) == false &&
                    !networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    mCallback.updateUi(null)
                    cancel(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg urls: String): Result? {
        var result: Result? = null
        if (!isCancelled && urls.isNotEmpty()) {
            val urlString = urls[0]
            result = try {
                val resultString = downloadUrl(urlString)
                if (resultString != null) {
                    val persons = ArrayList<Person>()
                    if (mPerson == null) {
                        Result(getAllPersons(urlString, persons))
                    }
                    else {
                        persons.add(getPersonHomeworldAndVehicles(urlString, mPerson))
                        Result(persons)
                    }
                } else {
                    throw IOException("No response received.")
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Result(e)
            }

        }
        return result
    }


    override fun onPostExecute(result: Result?) {
        mCallback?.apply {
            result?.mException?.also { exception ->
                updateUi(null)
                return
            }
            result?.mResultValue?.also { resultValue ->
                updateUi(resultValue)
                return
            }
            finishNetworking()
        }
    }
```

The problem is after i rotate the device, when i receive the callback from the asynctask, my views are not update, as the progress bar is still visible when i set progressBar.visibility = View.GONE

Comment: Where your async task code?

Comment: I edited my question with the asynctask

Answer (score 0):

OK so now i see that you call `callback.updateUi()` form the asyncTask functions.
This cause the problem because when you perform operations in async taks you are in non UI thread.
to avoid this problem you need to call runOnUiThread() inside you fucntion `override fun updateUi(result: ArrayList<Person>?)()` and surround all UI related code with the runOnUiThread block.

example:

```
override fun updateUi(result: ArrayList<Person>?) {

        runOnUiThread {
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
            if (result != null) {
                setAdapter(result)
            } else {
                finishNetworking()
                val snackBar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.root_layout),
                        "Network failure", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                snackBar.setAction("Try again") {
                    startDownload()
                }
                snackBar.show()
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Already tried runOnUiThread, when i dont rotate the screen the views are updated on the callback, but if i rotate the screen when the asynctask is still running, when the callback function is called, the views are not updated even running inside the runOnUiThread

Comment: Ohh ok this happens because when you rotate you screen you actually 'kill' you callback and later when the result comes from async task the callback is not exists already.